# Accessing nested array in a json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

let ages = data
  .filter(isDog)
  .map(dogYears)
  .reduce(sum);

mL/hr

i want to find the best way of accessing array elements in a javascript object. 
Eg: I want to find the first faculty name & first specializations for each course.

```
var students = 
{  
   deptartment:[  
      {  
         name:'Computer Science',
         age:20,
         Course:[  
            {  id: 100000
               name:'Object Oriented Programming',
               faculty:[  
                  {  
                     id:123,
                     name:'John',
                     Specialization: [
                       {name: 'science'},
                       {name: 'Physics'}
                     ]
                  }
                ]
            },
            {  id: 100001
               name:'C#',
               faculty:[    
                 {  
                     id:124,
                     name:'Denis', 
                     Specialization: [
                       {name: 'Ecnonomics'},
                       {name: 'Physics'}
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ],

      }
    ]
};
```

I know i can get the faculty name and specialization by

```
  var courses= deptartment && deptartment.Course ;
    var facultyWithSpecialization= {};
    if(courses){
      courses.forEach(course =>{
        var fname = course.faculty && course.faculty[0].name;
        var s= course.faculty && course.faculty.Specialization;
        facultyWithSpecialization[fname] = s && s[0].name;
      })
    }
```

use Object.assign({}, deptartment.Course) instead of department.Course

tried to use the below code but it doesn't make much difference.

```
 var courses=Object.values(Object.assign({}, deptartment.Course));
var fname = Object.values(Object.assign({}, course.faculty[0].Specialization[0]));
```

Expecting

```
'John': 'science'
'Denis': 'Ecnonomics'
```

Comment: There is no JSON in this question.

Comment: A. This is a JavaScript object. JSON is a string encoding

Comment: B. The question you have posted is filled with misspellings, including in the code. This may be your problem

Comment: *"I want the **first faculty name** and first specialization for each course"* - Then why would the result include `Denis`? That isn't the first faculty name.  Can you clarify?

Comment: faculty name and specialization(first).

Comment: Thank you. It would also be very helpful if you could validate your object and update the question accordingly. It's riddled with syntax errors, making it a pain to write code against it.

Comment: Not a  very user friendly structure for your expected results. What is your use case?

Comment: What if one person is teaching multiple courses? I'm with @charlietfl here. If you have any say over the structure of this data, I would change it. It seems strange that faculty members and their specialties are a child of a *course*. There should be separate properties: `course` and `faculty`, and perhaps the `course` has a `facultyId` that refers to a member of the `faculty`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. There were many error in the object including spelling mistakes and formatting

```js
var students = {
  deptartment: [{
    name: 'Computer Science',
    age: 20,
    Course: [{
      id: 100000,
      name: 'Object Oriented Programming',
      faculty: [{
          id: 123,
          name: 'John',
          Specialization: [{
              name: 'science'
            },
            {
              name: 'Physics'
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 124,
          name: 'Denis',
          Specialization: [{
              name: 'Ecnonomics'
            },
            {
              name: 'Physics'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }],

  }]
}
var obj = {};
students.deptartment.forEach((e) => {
  e.Course.forEach((k) => {
    k.faculty.forEach((l) => {
      obj[l.name] = l.Specialization[0].name
    })
  })
})
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant `department` instead of `deptartment`.
I modified a bit your JSON as it was a bit buggy:

```
var students = {  
   departments:[  
      {  
         name:'Computer Science',
         age:20,
         Courses:[  
            {  id: 100000,
               name:'Object Oriented Programming',
               faculty:[  
                  {  
                     id:123,
                     name:'John',
                     Specialization: [
                       {name: 'science'},
                       {name: 'Physics'}
                     ]
                  },
                 {  
                     id:124,
                     name:'Denis', 
                     Specialization: [
                       {name: 'Ecnonomics'},
                       {name: 'Physics'}
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ],
      }]
}
```

You can use `map` to achieve this nesting:

```
students.departments.map(
  department => department.Courses.map(
    course => course.faculty.map(
      student => ({
        name: student.name,
        specialization: student.Specialization[0].name // check nulls here!
      })
    )
  )
)
```